# Center an `<img>` in a `<div>`

Tags: html, css, margin, vertical-alignment

How do I center an `<img>` in a containing `<div>`?

The usual `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` isn't working.

The image can be larger than the container, and is scaled either horizontally or vertically by the `max-width` and `max-height`.

A jsfiddle with the below code: http://jsfiddle.net/9ShGj/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="http://www.yensa.com/fat/fat-dude10.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="container">
   <img src="http://oi43.tinypic.com/bje2wn.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: rgb(120, 120, 120);
 border: 1px solid red;
 margin: 5px;
}

.container img {
 max-width: 200px;
 max-height: 200px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write like this:

**CSS**

```
div{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:200px;
}

img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff&text=dummy" >
</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/dP89y/

Answer (score 1):

Image is not a block level element so need to convert it into block level element

So in your css add

```
.container img {
 display:block                /*ADD this line*/
 max-width: 200px;
 max-height: 200px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also you need to consider following points

```
Doctype : check whether it is not in quirks mode.

Width of inner div or image must me less that width of parent div.
```

do check these things you will get your answer...All the best.

Comment: You can do it without converting to a block, please look at Sandeep's answer above. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Right, this will also work. I have given answer if you are using margin:auto. All the best

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are making the img a block level element, you should be able to center it with:

```
.container { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: this only does horizontal centering

Answer (score 0):

Update following CSS... `vertical-align:middle; text-align:center`

```
   .container {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: rgb(120, 120, 120);
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin: 5px;
        vertical-align:middle; text-align:center //add this
    }
```