# centering image with vertical-align:middle in CSS not working

Tags: css, image, center, vertical-alignment

first time user of the site.  Im having an issue with vertically centering an image.  I've searched all over the web for different answers but couldnt find any.  I've tried using vertical-align: middle; but it doesnt work.  It centers horizontally, but not vertically.

heres the div with the image (which is a slideshow).  Thanks in advance!

```
<div id="photo">

                <img src="lax.jpg" name="slide" width="70%" height="70%">

                <script type="text/javascript">

                var step=1
                function slideit(){
                document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
                if(step<3)
                step++
                else
                step=1
                setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
                }
                slideit()

               </script>
            </div>
```

and the css

```
#photo{
position:absolute;
top:15%;
height:80%;
width: 70%;
left:20%;
background:#3377ff;
overflow:hidden;
```

}

```
img{
vertical-align:middle;
display: table-cell; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: This all depends greatly on the container elements.  Please provide the rest of the relevant code so we can help you without guessing.

Comment: You will get your answer here  

http://stackoverflow.com/q/13757783/699695

Answer (score 0):

try to remove this one

```
img{
vertical-align:middle;
display: table-cell; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
}
```

and add the contents in your div

```
  #photo{
     position:absolute;
     top:15%;
     height:80%;
     width: 70%;
     left:20%;
     background:#3377ff;
     overflow:hidden;
     vertical-align:middle;
     display: table-cell; 
     margin-left: auto; 
     margin-right: auto;
 }
```

Comment: i guess i should have mentioned that I have the div contained in a site which lies right in the middle.  Heres the code:

    #photo{
 position:absolute;
 top:15%;
 height:80%;
 width: 70%;
 left:20%;
 background:#3377ff;
 overflow:hidden;
}